# Php: Reading special characters in a variable from a required file

Tags: php, global-variables

There are three files: index.php, config.php and [language prefix].php.

Index sets basic settings (like the include path) and passes the control to "config.php.

Config sets a lot more things, including the language, and when it knows the language it requires the language file.

The language file stores some vars for static translation (like $menu=array('foo','bar','etc');)

I've done everything and tested everything(locally), but when i uploaded to the server, every variable which contained special characters (like áéíóúâêîôû etc...) declared outside index.php (either in config.php or in the language file) resulted in invalid characters(�), but if i declare it inside index, the characters appear normally.

As it worked locally, i am assuming that it should be due to a server setting. What should be the problem? (I have UTF-8 headers and the files are UTF-8 encoded)

**More info:**
I got a script to translate the date across languages, but it has words like "Sábado" which are correctly printed. The script itself is included by the template, but the vars are set and used inside the same file. Can require change the encoding of a file?

Comment: What is the encoding of your actual config file [I'm not referring to  the header encoding] Your index.php file may have the proper encoding but the config file may not. Depending on your code editor, you may be able to promote the other files to utf-8

Comment: I've edited all of the files with either VIM or gedit. (which i believe that default everything to UTF-8/ascii). Cpanel file manager also recognizes the files as UTF-8. And if they weren't encoded as UTF-8 how could i see everything locally?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your last question there but, what I would do is go into cpanel, copy the contents of config.php, delete the file, duplicate index.php, rename it to config.php, then paste the contents back in. Since you know index.php is the right encoding.

Comment: I just said that the files are fine (correct encoding). Please read the information i've added to the question. The problem seems to be related somehow with the variable being used in other file, but i am not sure nor know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor with which you can specify the encoding as UTF-8. I use TextPad. I also found with TextPad that when you are saving, you need to specify the file format as UNIX as opposed to PC. I don't do my main editing with TextPad, but it's useful for specifying the encoding.

UPDATE: I recently fount that TextPad doesn't handle UTF-8 encoding well, so I switched to Notepad++. I had another encoding problem that was quickly resolved after switching from TextPad to Notepad++.

Comment: I don't need such editor, i use GNU/Linux, so all my editors default to UNIX. The files are also encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Another possibility is the program that is doing your FTP transfer. How are you sending the files to the server?

Comment: Through FileZilla. Probably you know what you're talking about, but i can't see the point of changing the encode. Under cpanel the encode appears as UTF-8, so there was no change.

Comment: The point of troubleshooting is exploring all the possibilities. I'm sorry if I'm exploring blind alleys. FileZilla does a good job of transfering files, but I have known of people who still use antiquaded methods of uploading.

Comment: As you already said, it could be a server configuration. In the file httpd.conf, there is a line which specifies the encoding: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Save your files encoded as utf-8, set the page charset to be utf-8 and if there is data from db also set connection as utf-8.